# How can I use custom domains for my github page

Tags: github, dns, blogs, cname

I have a github page([lc87624.github.com](http://lc87624.github.com)), and I want my domains("[www.gemoji.me](http://www.gemoji.me)" and "[blog.gemoji.me](http://blog.gemoji.me)") link to this page. 
I try to add two CNAME record pointing to "[lc87624.github.com](http://lc87624.github.com)", but when I visit my domains, it shows a error page of github saying "Page does not exist! ". Someone can help me?

PS: My github page is a blog using a framework named "octopress", and I have added a CNAME file to the source branch.

Comment: You can get it [HERE](http://pages.github.com/). :)

Comment: @Kjuly, I have seen this page before, and add two CNAME record, but I don't know why github show me "Page does not exist". Should I add 'A' record?

Comment: The answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222822/how-do-i-configure-dns-in-godaddy-control-panel-to-point-domain-to-github-page helped me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I checked your repo and found that you haven't own a `CNAME` file in your `master` branch, which was used to show your site. Maybe you forgot to **generate** the site after added the `CNAME` file to your `source`.
You can have a look at [MINE](https://github.com/Kjuly/kjuly.github.com). :)

Comment: You're right, I just pushed the CNAME file to the source branch. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Kjuly: Do I understand it correctly that your site is hosted by your own at `http://dev.kjuly.com/` and `kjuly.github.io` makes only a redirect? Is it possible to use the custom domain (e.g. `dev.kjuly.com`) but still host it on GitHub? What do I have to do at the side of `dev.kjuly.com` to use the files hosted at GitHub?

Comment: @moose I use Github's Page service, and made a CNAME record to Github. So guests can visit `dev.kjuly.com` instead of `kjuly.github.io` (this is only for site that didn't offer CNAME), all my site's resource are hosted at Github: https://github.com/Kjuly/kjuly.github.com. You can take a look at this [LINK](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) for more help. ;)

Comment: @Kjuly: Thanks for clarification. But I still don't understand how to solve my problem. I think I need a more detailed explanation  than one that can be done with comments, so I've started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20867632/562769

Comment: @moose answerd your question. :)