# How can I use Jekyll with my domain, but hosted on GitHub?

Tags: dns, jekyll, cname

I would like to switch from WordPress to Jekyll. I already have migrated the articles (see new Jekyll articles + rendered page and old WordPress site).

Now I would like to have the old URLs:

```
Old URL        :      http://martin-thoma.com/word-error-rate-calculation/
Current new URL: http://martinthoma.github.io/word-error-rate-calculation/
```

So this question is really only about the top level domain. My provider (called "Knallhart") should only "hold" the domain `martin-thoma.com` (GitHub does not offer this, do they?) and GitHub should serve the content.

When a user enters `http://martin-thoma.com/word-error-rate-calculation/` or `http://martinthoma.github.io/word-error-rate-calculation/` the browser should show `http://martin-thoma.com/word-error-rate-calculation/`, although the content is at GitHub.

I know the GitHub page [Setting up a custom domain with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages), but I still don't understand what I should do.

I've tried adding a CNAME file with content `martin-thoma.com` to my GitHub repository, but this only lead to an redirect from `martinthoma.github.io` to `martin-thoma.com`. I've just tried adding a CNAME with content `martinthoma.github.io` on the webspace provided by Knallhart. This seems to have no effect.

I think I have to change something on GitHub as well as with Knallhart. GitHub has to know that it should display `martin-thoma.com` and Knallhart has to redirect to the content. But I don't understand how to do this. **What do I have to change on GitHub and what do I have to do on side of my provider?**

Can I do this by my own or do I need support from Knallhart? I currently have a quite cheap plan that basically only offers Hosting+PHP+MySQL. If I pay 6€ more, I get a Zone-Modul (which has the description "DNS controll for your domain"). **Do I need a Zone-Modul?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [HELP PAGE](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) said:

> For a domain like example.com, you should use an A record pointing to 204.232.175.78:

In your case, you need to create an `A` record for `martin-thoma.com`, take mine as an example (I don't use Knallhart, maybe it's different, just make sure you make a `A` record to `204.232.175.78`, which Github offers):

```
Host               |record type | host/IP  
*.kjuly.com         A             204.232.175.78 (Edit: NOT Recommended)  
@.kjuly.com         A             204.232.175.78
```

**Note**: `CNAME` record is for subdomains like `dev.martin-thoma.com`.

---

### EDIT (IMPORTANT):

Depend on the Github's official blog post ["GitHub Pages Legacy IP Deprecation"](https://github.com/blog/1917-github-pages-legacy-ip-deprecation), the `204.232.175.78` is deprecated, you should use `192.30.252.153` or `192.30.252.154` instead.

```
Host               |record type | host/IP  
@.kjuly.com         A             192.30.252.153
```

Comment: What is an `A` record and how do I create it? What about the Zone-Modul question?

Comment: @moose you need to login your domain name's manage console on your Domain Name provider site ("Knallhart" as yours) to add this record. Generally speaking, there're 3 types of records at least: A, CNAME & MX. What you need it the `A` record. Just add it. If you cannot find it, you can contact your Domain Name Provider for help. ;)

Comment: @moose seems u do need that service called `Zone-Modul`, otherwise you cannot control your domain name's DNS. When you want to use Github to host your resource, you do not need `Hosting+PHP+MySQL` service anymore. What you need is only the domain name. Where did you registered the domain name? Knallhart? I recommend you to use `http://godaddy.com` or else. Or you can contact Knallhart for help if they can help you modify the DNS records. :)

Comment: Than you for your help. I've just talked with them and they changed ... something (free of charge :-) ). Now I get a 404 from GitHub when I enter `http://martin-thoma.com/`, but `http://martinthoma.github.io/` does not return a 404. Do you know why? What can I try to find out what caused the error?

Comment: @moose cool. You need to add a CNAME file (CNAME or A record are all use this file to tell Github your domain name) into your resource witch hosted on Github. You can take a look at mine (another site uses A record): https://github.com/Kjuly/kjuly.com/blob/gh-pages/CNAME

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It works now as I expected it to work :-)